# FedEx Track Web Service isn't recognizing any tracking numbers

Tags: fedex

I'm trying to use the FedEx API to track packages. I can authenticate to their test server successfully (using my user credentials, account number, and meter number). However, I receive the same unhelpful response for most tracking numbers that I use in my requests; both test tracking numbers (like 999999999999) and real tracking numbers (that work well on the FedEx website) return the following:

> Error Code 9040. 
>   No information for the following shipments has been received by our system yet.  Please try again or contact Customer Service at 1.800.Go.FedEx(R) 800.463.3339.

The only requests that fetch a different response are the clearly invalid ones, like "test", which returns:

> Error Code 5508.
>   Invalid tracking number.

I tried SOAP requests using their wsdl (TrackService_v5) as well as manual non-SOAP HTTP POST requests, but their responses are exactly the same in both cases. Is something wrong on their side, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Switching to the production server fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that FedEx has disabled any test tracking numbers, in the past 999999999999 would work just fine, but now that doesn't even work. To the best of my knowledge, the only way to resolve this is to move to production. Which IMHO is bad because you have to test the tracking part of your application until you move to production.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

999999999999 worked for me, but I think I am already in production environment.

[image: 999999999999]